# Boost::coroutine example not works

Tags: c++, boost, boost-coroutine

Boost library has interesting thing - coroutines. I try simple example [factorial](https://github.com/erikfrey/coroutine/blob/master/libs/coroutine/example/factorial.cpp) But is error:

> factorial.cpp(35): error C2039: 'self' : is not a member of 'boost::coroutines::coroutine'

How compile this and others examples?
Maybe I bad install Boost ? I only copy boost_1_55_0\boost subdirectory

Comment: erikfrey/coroutine from github works! It is different boost subpackage?

Answer (score 0):

it seams that you mix up the factorial example from the deprecated boost.coroutine lib from Giovanni P. Deretta with the official boost.coroutine library (contained in the boost package).